# Citrix has hijacked my escape key; how do I get it back?

Tags: browser, hotkeys, citrix-receiver

By company policy I must access Citrix via the web client to get to my work desktop. When I elect to go fullscreen, when I press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, the window pops back into the browser.

That would be fine if that's what I wanted. What I want is for <kbd>ESC</kbd> to be sent to the application I'm working in with my desktop.

I looked around and found that `launch.ica` (the file that starts the remote session) can be customized, but didn't see anything related to this.

Comment: I am pretty sure Citrix requires the use of a modifier key to pass a key command like the escape key (especially if its existing full screen mode) have you tried to use the Citrix modifer key?

Comment: This is standard browser behavior. ESC will absolutely and always exit full screen mode. It’s a hard-wired default so you cannot be locked in your browser.

Comment: @DanielB, Shoot. It was the "man" in the middle. I forgot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DanielB pointed out: it's not Citrix that did the hijacking. It's that the browsers' escape from fullscreen via <kbd>ESC</kbd> is in play, and has no awareness of Citrix being run.

Maybe there are [some contortions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916109/prevent-esc-key-from-exiting-fullscreen-app-mode-on-website) to bypass this.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the Citrix option to make the window fullscreen. Use the browsers option for fullscreen by clicking it in main menu. E.g. in Chrome:
[Chrome fullscreen option in main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDNgC.png)

Comment: Much easier solution. This works on chrome (F11 for full-screen).